# Perform segue while view is presenting modal view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want a view behind a modal view to push to (or present) another view before the modal view is dismissed so that the transition is behind the modal view.

At the moment from a delegate in the modal view I am calling `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` on the view presenting the modal view but when the modal view is dismissed the view has not changed and becomes unresponsive. Is there a way to achieve this effect?

```
extension InitialViewController: LoggedInDelegate {
    func loggedIn() {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToVerification", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the modal view a third-party library?

Comment: @rigdonmr No it's just a standard modal view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this by changing the modal presentation style to either `Over Full Screen` or `Over Current Context`. Both worked.